# Endless Refresh loop of ASP.NET Core 6 MVC pages with Internet Explorer 11

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, .net-core, internet-explorer-11

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC site that works fine in all browsers except IE11. I have a suspicious comportement in all pages, it reloads each page indefinitely, but when I click inside the page, it stops reloading.
My web site contains a `Startup.cs` class and a master page

I can't find the problem, and I'm looking if there is a solution or a contournement

Comment: You haven't provide enough information for anyone to suggest any solution. Please, debug more and provide more details.

Comment: Do some public websites have the same problem, e.g. Google or Bing? You could disable the meta refresh function in Internet Explorer, this might help for you. `Internet Options` -> `Security` tab -> `local Intranet` -> `custom level` -> `Allow META REFRESH` -> Disable. In addition, IE is about to end support, I think you could focus more on user experience in modern browsers.